# Unsplitting lines with ArcGIS tool 'Unsplit Lines'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polyline-creation

I have tried to use the ArcGIS tool 'Unsplit lines' to get one polyline from multiple touching lines. Somehow, it does not work with some features. Have a look at the pic nr 1.
[image] In the pic you see one door from a 'door layer'. With this (and other doors) the unsplitting did only partially work, as it is still separated into four lines. However, I had a look at the vertices, and they share relevant vertices. Still, they don't merge. When I had a look at the vertices the connection is only start node with start node, or end node with end node. As such, I concluded, that with the Unsplit tool only start node and end node will form a connection? I wish I could include an adequate picture showing the vertices of all lines. However, in ArcGIS you can view the vertices of only one feature at a time. 
Now my question: Is there another possibility to get the door to become one single feature? Dissolve is not an option as I have many many doors in the layer and, unfortunately, the line features do not have a field saying to which door they belong. As such I cannot dissolve per field. The result is, therefore, a layer in which all doors belond to one single multipart feature, which is not what I need. I need each door being a single feature, this should be done by using some kind of automation as there are many many doors.

Of course I had more than one look in the internet to find answers and tried these tools in ArcGIS: Unsplit lines, Dissolve (not an option), Merge (as this needs selection, this is also not an option). I tried aggregate, but it throws an error, besides that it would give some problems as some doors overlap.

Accordingly I would probably need a tool, which merges line features which share a node without that the sharin nodes need to have the properties start node-end node. Do some of you know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the Editor Toolbar, Merge or Union?

Comment: Try merge, specify some attributes to merge with, then explode.

Comment: Try tool Integrate with a very small value and then unsplit lines. Backup your data before you try since Integrate will modify existing data

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for you answers! I'm not sure if I explained my problem correctly, but as I have a very big layer with hundreds of doors segmented into parts without having an identifier showing to which door a segment belongs to I think neither Merge nor Union would've done the job. And what exactly was meant with the editor toolbar?

However, I found a rather work around which helped to get exactly what I wanted.

1. I make a buffer with a very small distance around all door segments. I used here 0.1 m. This will result in buffering each segment of each single door. As the segments of one door are very close to each other, their buffers will overlap.
2. Then I used the dissolve tool, with both options (Unsplit, create multipart feature) **un**checked. Then I have one single buffer for each door.
3. In order to be able to use the spatial join tool, I need to include a new field, which I named 'IDnew'. This field includes the FIDs. Accordingly, I put IDnew = OBJECT_ID into the Field Calculator. This step needs to be taken, as the tool spatial join tool does not give the option to join over the ObjectID.
4. Then I spatial join the door file (target) with the buffer file (join). The result will be, that the doors are still segmented, but each segment now has the ID of the door to which it belongs to.
5. Dissolve the door file over the IDnew field. This results in de-fragmented door features, for each door one complete feature. Voilà.

All was done in ArcGIS.